# How to get dummy with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the next table:

```
| Name | TagID |  Key  |
|------|-------|-------|
| a    |   285 |     1 |
| a    |   101 |     0 |
| a    |   200 |     1 |
| a    |  1601 |     0 |
| a    |  1991 |     0 |
| a    |  7075 |     0 |
| b    |   285 |     1 |
| b    |   132 |     0 |
| b    |   101 |     0 |
| b    |   200 |     1 |
| b    |   165 |     0 |
| b    |  1617 |     0 |
| b    |   160 |     0 |
| b    |   334 |     1 |
| c    |   285 |     1 |
| c    |  1123 |     1 |
| c    |   200 |     0 |
```

I want to get a table with the shape (unique `Names` × unique `TagID`) and with 1 if `TagID` has `Key` = 1.

**Question:** How to do this in the most efficient way? 
Just, I have about 1 mln rows and 3k unique `TagID`.

E.g.:

```
|   | 101 | 132 | 160 | 165 | 200 | 285 | 334 | 1123 | 1601 | 1617 | 1991 | 7075 |
|---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|------|------|------|------|------|
| a |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| b |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| c |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), replace missing values and cast to integers or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot('Name','TagID','Key').fillna(0).astype(int)
#alternative
#df1 = df.set_index(['Name','TagID'])['Key'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
TagID  101   132   160   165   200   285   334   1123  1601  1617  1991  7075
Name                                                                         
a         0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
b         0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
c         0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

EDIT: If get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means duplicates in `Name` and `TagID`, so is necessary aggregate `max`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Name','TagID'])['Key'].max().unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='Name',
                     columns='TagID',
                     values='Key',
                     fill_value=0,
                     aggfunc='max')

print (df2)
TagID  101   132   160   165   200   285   334   1123  1601  1617  1991  7075
Name                                                                         
a         0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
b         0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
c         0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @lemon - There are only `0` and `1` values?

Comment: for `Key` column - Yes